# Bruhat decomposition over algebraically nonclosed fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a group over algebraically nonclosed field $k$ of characteristic $0$. And let $P$ be a minimal parabolic subgroup defined over $k$. Let $S$ be its maximal split torus and $T$ be its maximal torus defined over $k$ containing $S$ ($P\supset T \supset S$). Let $W(T)=N_G(T)/Z_G(T)$ and $W(S)=N_G(S)/Z_G(S)$ be the corresponding Weyl groups. Then we have Bruhat decomposition over $\overline{k}$  $G/P=\bigcup_{n\in N_G(T)(\overline{k})}PnP/P$ and by Borel-Tits we also have the decomposition for $k$ points i.e. $G(k)/P(k)=\bigcup_{w\in N_G(S)(k)}P(k)wP(k)/P(k)$ (which is different from above but each class $P(k)wP(k)/P(k)$ is Zariski dense in the corresponding class $PwP/P$ of the first decomposition). There is a remark 6.24 b) in the paper of Borel and Tits that it can happen that $PnP/P$ is defined over $k$ but does not contain $k$-points. I have the following questions about this issue:

0) What is the easiest example of this phenomenon?

1) Is there a reasonable condition on the field when this cannot happen?

2) Is there a reasonable condition on the field (Galois group) when this issue does not happen for the given minimal group $P$ and all possible parabolics of $G$ such that $Q\supset P$ and $Q/Rad Q$ is of split rank $1$? I.e. this issue does not happen for Bruhat decomposition of $Q/P$.

Remark (Introduced after a discussion): Given $n\in N_G(T)(k_s)$,there is a possibility that the smooth locally closed subscheme $P_{k_s}nP_{k_s}$ inside $G_{k_s}$ can be defined over $k$. (This of course happens if $^\gamma n\in N_{Z_G(S)}(T)n N_{Z_G(S)}(T)$ for all $\gamma \in {\rm{Gal}}(k_s/k)$, so the question for particular $n$ is reduced to the Galois action on the set $W(G,T)$ which is reduced to combinatorics of the root system. The question is about reasonable conditions on the field $k$ for the following to be true: if $P_{k_s}nP_{k_s}$ is defined over $k$ then it contains a $k$-point (or equivalently by the Bruhat decomposition for $G(k)$ with respect to $P(k)$, is necessarily equal to $P_{k_s}n'P_{k_s}$ for some $n' \in N_G(S)(k)$).

Comment: Writing $W_k$ to denote the relative Weyl group (which is not the group of $k$-points of what you call $W$) and simultaneously writing $H_k$ to denote the group of $k$-points of a $k$-group ($P_k, G_k, N_G(S)_k$, etc.) is rather confusing notation. Can you please denote the group of $k$-points in another way, such as $H(k)$?  While doing that, please also replace $G_k$ with $G(k)/P(k)$. The subsets $(PwP)(\overline{k})$ for $w\in W(G,S)$ are pairwise disjoint, so can you please also clarify your reason for interest in the possibility that some $PwP$ for $w\in W(G,T)$ is defined over $k$?

Comment: Thank you for noticing confusion in my notations. I can understand the reason for putting $P(k)$ instead of $P_k$, but what you can advise me to change $N_G(S)_k$ for? $N(G,S)(k)$?

Comment: I think that $N_G(S)(k)$ is reasonable notation.  Since the finite etale $k$-group $W(G,S) = N_G(S)/Z_G(S)$ turns out to be constant with group of $k$-points always equal to $N_G(S)(k)/Z_G(S)(k)$ (a real miracle, in my opinion), one can also safely index those unions by the groups $W(G,T)(\overline{k})$ and $W(G,S)(k)$ respectively (where it is understood that $PwP$ means $P n_w P$ for a representative $n_w$ of $w$, the choice of which doesn't matter for the double coset).

Comment: I think that the issue @nfdc23 brings up has not been addressed by the edit.  You're still writing $G_k$ sometimes and $N_G(S)(k)$ sometimes.  Do these both mean the group of rational points?

Comment: Also, what does your (2) mean?  Do you mean to consider the same group $P$ as a parabolic inside several different groups $G$?  I don't think that this can happen in any reasonable way.

Comment: Finally, you mention a remark in Borel–Tits.  Where in the paper does this remark appear?  I had a quick glance near (5.15), where the rational Bruhat decomposition is discussed, and didn't see it.  It seems unlikely:  for $PwP/P$ to be defined over $k$, it would have to be Galois-stable, which, by the geometric Bruhat decomposition, indicates that $w$ lies in $W(G, S)(k)$, hence, as @nfdc23 mentions, has a lift to $N_G(S)(k)$.

Comment: @LSpice: Since $N_G(S)$ doesn't lie inside $N_G(T)$, if $w \in N_G(T)(k_s)$ and $P_{k_s}wP_{k_s}$ arises from a $k$-subgroup of $G$, it isn't clear if that "$P$-double coset" has any $k$-point. So in principle the possibility that is being said to be mentioned in some Remark of Borel-Tits isn't obviously ruled out.

Comment: @nfdc23, I have deleted my comments, which I now think are irrelevant.  I think that the point is the one you have pointed out:  contrary to what is implicit in the statement, there is no such thing as "the corresponding class in the first [geometric] decomposition".  Instead, I think that the point is that a given class $P w P$ with $w \in N_G(S)(k_{\text s})$ may be a union of 'Bruhat' cells (although I prefer to reserve Bruhat cells for Borel double cosets …), hence may be defined over $k$ without any of the individual cells being so defined (hence having a rational point).

Answer (score 1):

There is the following example when the remark of Borel and Tits is obviously true. Consider the group $G=SL(2, \Bbb D)$ over division algebra $\Bbb D$ for example $\Bbb H$ for $k=\Bbb R$. The parabolic subgroup is the following

\begin{pmatrix}
\Bbb H^\times &  \Bbb H \\
0 & \Bbb H^\times 
\end{pmatrix}

Then it has split rank $1$, so the Bruhat decomposition for $k$-points is just $G_k=P_k\cup P_ksP_k$, where $s\in N_G(S)(k)$ (of course over $\Bbb C$ the cell $P/P$ is the point and the cell $PsP/P$ is open). Hovewer if we pass to the points of $G$ over $\Bbb C$ then $G/P(\Bbb C)$  is the Grassmanian  $G(2,4)$ of $2$-dim vector subspaces of $4$-dim. Then there is a $P$-invariant open subset of the unique divisor which consists of $2$-dimensional vector spaces intersecting a given one that is stabilized by $P$. (This subspace correspond to the first block in the matrix and is clear that the condition on the intersection is preserved by the action of $P$). It is clear that being unique such divisor is Galois invariant,   however it does not have the points defined over $k=\Bbb R$ on the dense open $P$-orbit.